# How Do I Join A SQL Pivot Query That Uses Delare Statements to a Normal SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

Sorry if this isn't the best way to ask this but I am stuck at this point, I have tried researching but to no avail, trying to join these two queries:

```
SELECT [id]
  ,[title]
  ,[desc]
FROM [localTest].[dbo].[main];

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols  = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Year]) from [localTest].[dbo].[Years] FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    set @query = 'SELECT [ID], ' + @cols + ' from (select [ID], [Year], [Amount] FROM [localTest].[dbo].[Years] ) x pivot (min([Amount]) for [Year] in (' + @cols + ')) p '
execute(@query);
```

Looking for the final result here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8lJs.jpg)

Comment: In my image Table One is the result of the first query and Table Two is the result of the second query...looking to join these together to achieve the Final Result in the image.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, here is my solution:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
 SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Year]) FROM [localTest].[dbo].[Years] FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(max);
 SELECT @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM [localTest].[dbo].[main] a join (
            SELECT * FROM (
                  SELECT [ID] id, [Year], [Amount]
                    FROM [localTest].[dbo].[Years]
            ) x pivot (
                    min([Amount])
                    for [Year] IN ('+@cols+')
            ) p ) as b on a.[ID] = b.id';
EXECUTE(@Sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the result of second query to a `#temp` table and join the `#temp` table to `main` table like below:

```
    SELECT [id]
      ,[title]
      ,[desc]
  FROM [localTest].[dbo].[main];


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols  = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Year]) from [localTest].[dbo].[Years] FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    set @query = 'SELECT [ID], ' + @cols + ' from (select [ID], [Year], [Amount] FROM [localTest].[dbo].[Years] ) x pivot (min([Amount]) for [Year] in (' + @cols + ')) p '

insert into #temp
execute(@query);

select * from [localTest].[dbo].[main]  AS  a inner join #temp as b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thanks...but I'm getting an error: invalid object name #temp.

Comment: That is the temp table name, you must create. #temp is the temporary table what i used for demonstrating.

Comment: This works: select * into #temp1 from [localTest].[dbo].[main] 
select * from #temp1; I get output, but every combination I've tried to replace the second query (the one with DECLARE) where [localTest].[dbo].[main]  is...still getting errors.